# Finding the Difference By Row Between 2 Columns that are Both Arrays in SnowSql

Tags: php, sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, array-difference

I have a dataset that is comprised of a date and two other columns that are in array format. I am trying to find all the values in array_1 that are not in array_2.

```
Date | Array_1     | Array_2
-------------------------
1/20 | [1,2,3]     | [1,2]
2/20 | [4,5,6]     | [[1,2,4]
```

Desired Output:

```
    Date | Array_1     
    --------------
    1/20 | [3]    
    2/20 | [5,6]
```

Comment: If you want to use sql for this, consider normalising your data

Comment: @Strawberry The reason they are listed as an array is because that was the only way I could think to aggregate the data initially. It's possible there is another way. The two features I'm looking at for my data are submissions and logins. I'm trying to find all the users in my data that logged in a quarter but did not submit. I'm looking to get that for every quarter in my dataset. I have no issue doing this for one specific quarter, but doing it for all quarters has caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to remind that if you were to use application code for this, it might be as simple as (using PHP for this example):

```
$array1 = array(4,5,6);
$array2 = array(5,6,7);

print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

Outputs: `Array ( [0] => 4 )`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is:

- Unnest ("flatten") the values into two tables.
- Use set functions for the operation you want.
- Re-aggregate to an array.

I don't have Snowflake on hand, but I think this is how it works:

```
select t.*, array_3
from t left join lateral
     (select array_agg(el) as array_3
      from (select array_1
            from table(flatten(input ==> t.array_1)) a1
            except
            select array_2
            from table(flatten(input ==> t.array_2)) a2
           ) x
     ) x
```